# Is there a way to join a thread in another function? (I.E. Outside of it's own scope)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

Let's say I am creating multiple threads, based on the amount of arguments I gave to the program when I ran it. The code for it would something like this:

```
ProgThread aProgThreads[nArgc-1];
for(int p=0;p<nArgc-1;p++){
    aProgThreads[p].init();
}
```

The code above would create an object for every argument. After that, it will call the `init()` function for every object. In this function the thread will be made like this:

```
void ProgThread::init(){
    std::thread oMainThread(&ProgThread::loop, *this); //Creates a thread that executes the loop function
}
```

Now, because I'm dealing with multiple threads I want to execute at the same time I can't join them within the `init()` function. This means I have to join them after they have all been created. The way this code is currently written, this isn't possible because `oMainThread` won't exist outside of the `init()` function. Is there a way I can make it so I can have a seperate loop that joins all the threads? It would look something like this:

```
for(int p=0;p<nArgc-1;p++){
        aProgThreads[p].joinThread();
}
```

Coupled with

```
void ProgThread::joinThread(){
    oMainThread.join();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make `oMainThread` a member of your `ProgThread` class. This way it will be available both at `ProgThread::init` as well as `ProgThread::joinThread`.

Comment: `init()` ? In C++, we use constructors to initialize objects. `ProgThread aProgThreads[nArgc-1];` already calls `ProgThread::ProgThread` for each object.

Comment: @MSalters, Sometimes you want to "initialize" something, but it's not convenient to do so at the time when the object is constructed.The OP's problem nicely illustrates the fact:  OP was discouraged from making the array of `std::thread` a member because the `std::thread` class gives you no way to construct the object without also starting the thread. IMO: `std::thread` would be more versatile if it worked like Java's `java.lang.Thread` class: In Java, you can construct a `Thread` instance, and then `start()` it later.

Comment: IMO: The main reason for a constructor to exist is to leave the new object in a state where the destructor can be safely called. If it's _convenient_, the constructor can also do other stuff, but that's just gravy.

Comment: @SolomonSlow [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) has a default constructor that creates a `std::thread` that "does not represent a thread"

Comment: @SolomonSlow on second thought I think I know what you mean. It would require to write a wrapper if you want to pass the function already at construction but only want to start the thread later

Comment: @MSalters I simplified this example so the question became more clear. When I want to make the thread, it takes a few arguments that I want to give it. That's the reason I've chosen to do it this way

Answer (score 2):

The chief problem in your example is `std::thread oMainThread` in `onInit`. This creates a thread, yes, but it also tries to destroy the thread when you return from `onInit`. And that will indeed fail, because `oMainThread` has not been joined.

Instead, the `join` needs to be in the destructor of `ProgThread`, which means `oMainThread` needs to be a member. And of course, like all members, it should be initialized in the constructor of `ProgThread`.

The only reason why you'd want a loop is when your threads need to be told when to stop before joining. In that case, it can be wise to tell all threads to stop, and only then start joining them. It would take more time to tell one thread to stop, then join that thread, then tell the next, etcetera.

Comment: I tried to make it a member of the function. Sadly, when I compile it, it gives me an error that says ```‘OsThread::OsThread(const OsThread&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed``` & ```note: declared here
     thread(const thread&) = delete;```. Is there any way I can change the declaration in the header for it to resolve the error?

Comment: Do you understand the error? That's the default copy constructor. You can't copy a running thread. The fix here depends on the circumstances. Why are you trying to copy a `OsThread`, and what should that mean?

Comment: Ohh it appears I've made a syntax mistake in the constructor. Instead of typing ```ProgThread::ProgThread() : oMainThread(std::thread(&ProgThread::loop, *this))``` I put it likes this ```ProgThread::ProgThread() : oMainThread(&ProgThread::loop, *this)```
Thanks for your help!